# Contact Us Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Contact Us page that is not working. there is this error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server
>   response was: From domain must match authenticated domain at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, 
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection 
>   conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at 
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddress
>   Collection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, 
>   SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at 
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at 
>   Pages_Public_Contact.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
>   c:\Users\Vanguardo66\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   2013\WebSites\TelerikWebSite2\Pages\Public\Contact.aspx.cs:line 27

and this is my code-behind:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage((Session["User"] == "Guest" ? txtFromUnknown.Text.Trim() : UserCheck.ReturnUserInfo(4)), "ops@gitamarine.com", "Visiting", txtText.Text.Trim());
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.gitamarine.com");
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("website@gitamarine.com", "*********");
            smtp.Port = 2525;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblAlert.Text = "Error: " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

So I tried this but no luck!!! how does it work? I don't know!!!
any way I am new to this please help.

Comment: The error states the problem `From domain must match authenticated domain` you can't set the from address to the users email address, this would require an open relay mail server. Use the same from address that you used to do authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states the problem `From domain must match authenticated domain` you can't set the from address to the users email address, this would require an open relay mail server. Use the same from address that you used to do authentication